# Using fences to clean-up command buffers and synchronizing swap chain images at the same time

Tags: graphics, vulkan

Say I have a swap chain consisting of `n` images and I allow `k` "frames in flight". I ensure correct synchronization between `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`, `vkQueueSubmit` and `vkQueuePresentKHR` by a set of semaphores `imageAvailableSemaphore` and `renderFinishedSemaphore` and a fence `imageInFlight` like it is done in [this tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Rendering_and_presentation):

```
imageAvailableSemaphores.resize(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);
    renderFinishedSemaphores.resize(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);
    inFlightFences.resize(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);
```

The fences are needed to ensure that we don't use the semaphores again before the GPU has completed consuming the corresponding image. So, this fence needs to be specified in `vkQueueSubmit`.

On the other hand, I'm creating command buffers independently of the "frames in flight". They are "one-time submit" command buffers. Hence, once submitted, I add them to a "to-be-deleted" list. I need to know when the GPU has finished execution of the command buffers in this list.

But I cannot specify another fence in `vkQueueSubmit`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

> I allow `k` "frames in flight"

Well, that's your answer. Each thread that is going to contribute command buffers for a "frame" should have some multiple of `k` command buffers. They should use them in a ring-buffer fashion. These command buffers should be created from a transient-allocating pool. When they pick the least-recently used CB from the ring buffer, they should reset it before recording into it.

You ensure that no thread tries to reset a CB that is still in use by not *starting* any work for the next frame until the `k`th frame in the past has completed (using a fence).

If for some reason you absolutely *cannot* tell your threads what `k` is up front, you're still going to have to tell them *something*. When you start work on the thread, you need to tell them how many frames are still in fight. This allows them to check the size of their ring buffer against this number of frames. If the number of elements in the ring buffer is less than the number of frames, then the oldest CB in the ring buffer is not in use. Otherwise, it will have to allocate a new CB from the pool and shove that into the ring buffer.

Comment: (a) So, in a single thread, for each frame `i = 0, ..., k - 1` we have `a[i]` command buffers `cb[i][0], ..., cb[i][a[i] - 1]`, all allocated from a *common* transient-allocating pool? Or do you suggest to use a dedicated pool for each `i`? (b) And you suggest to reset the entire pool after each command buffer has been used once?

Comment: (c) In any case, this seems to indicate that each command buffer corresponds to precisely one swap chain. But what happens if I have a command buffer which uses images from more than one swap chain or which not only renders into a swap chain image, but also into a texture?

Comment: I'd be really interested in your response; especially to (c).

Comment: @0xbadf00d: (a) and (b) are too generic to provide answers for, as they depend entirely on what you're doing and how you plan to do it in each thread. And (c) is kind of beside the point. If you define a "frame" as rendering to a single swapchain image, then that's what you need to work with. If you define a "frame" as rendering to two swap chain images, then *that* is what you need to work with. The point is that you need to properly communicate the data that the new frame is allowed to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Timeline Semaphores for this. You can read in depth about them here: https://www.khronos.org/blog/vulkan-timeline-semaphores

Instead of being signaled or not signaled timeline semaphores carry a specific value. The function interesting for you is vkGetSemaphoreCounterValue, which allows you to read the value of the semaphore without blocking.

To create a timeline semaphore you simply set the pNext value of your VkSemaphoreCreateInfo to a VkSemaphoreTypeCreateInfo looking like the following.

```
VkSemaphoreTypeCreateInfo 
timelineCreateInfo{VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SEMAPHORE_TYPE_CREATE_INFO};
timelineCreateInfo.semaphoreType = VK_SEMAPHORE_TYPE_TIMELINE;
timelineCreateInfo.initialValue = 0;
```

The pNext value of your VkSubmitInfo needs to be set to a VkTimelineSemaphoreSubmitInfo.

```
VkTimelineSemaphoreSubmitInfo timelineInfo{VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_TIMELINE_SEMAPHORE_SUBMIT_INFO};
timelineInfo.signalSemaphoreValueCount = 1;
timelineInfo.pSignalSemaphoreValues = &signalValue;
```

After the command buffer is done the value of the semaphore will be whatever value you set signalValue to. After that you can query for the value with:

```
uint64_t value;
vkGetSemaphoreCounterValue(device, semaphore, &value);
```

So assuming you set signalValue to 1 value here will be either 1 or 0 which is what we gave the semaphore as initial value in VkSemaphoreTypeCreateInfo. After that you can safely delete your one time command buffer.

Note: Timeline Semaphores are actually meant as a semi replacement of fences and binary semaphores and should be the main synchronization primitive you use. I think the only function that requires a binary semaphore is vkAcquireSwapchainImage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already taken a look at timeline semaphores in the past, but there are two issues which prevented me from using them: (a) They are only a device extension and hence may not be supported by a GPU. (b) As mentioned in the blog article, "Vulkan’s window system integration APIs do not yet support timeline semaphores". So, I don't see how I could use them to synchronize `vkAcquireSwapchainImage` and `vkQueueSubmit`.

Comment: a) They are a core feature of Vulkan 1.2 and any GPU supporting that will have them. b) you can combine them with binary semaphores. All you have to do is add the semaphore you used for vkAcquireSwapchainImage to the list of waitsemaphores and add dummy value in the timeline sbmit info.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. What's not clear to me yet: How are the timeline semaphores help me to solve my problem? Which aspect of what I'm trying to achieve, wouldn't been possible with ordinary semaphores/fences?

Comment: Really be interested in your response.

Comment: @0xbadf00d If you're still curious, there's nothing about what you're trying to do that _requires_ timeline semaphores. However, timeline semaphores are nice: you can signal and wait on them from both the host and device and query them from the host. You can't touch binary semaphores from the host side, and you can't signal fences on the host nor wait on them from the device. Also, you can replace several binary semaphores/fences with one timeline semaphore, which is more efficient. They arguably make for cleaner code, too. https://www.khronos.org/blog/vulkan-timeline-semaphores